# Laravel Unable to change loginPath

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created an AdminAuthController and Admin model that are duplicates of AuthController and Users respectively.
Im using Users/AuthControllers for my users and Admin for Admin controls and login

I have my routes as:

---

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function(){

  // Authentication routes...
  Route::get('auth/login', ['as' => 'adminLogin', 'uses' => 'Admin\Auth\AdminAuthController@getLogin']);
  Route::post('auth/login', 'Admin\Auth\AdminAuthController@postLogin');
  Route::get('auth/logout', ['as' => 'adminLogout', 'uses' => 'Admin\Auth\AdminAuthController@getLogout']);

  // Registration routes...
  Route::get('auth/register', ['as' => 'adminRegister', 'uses' => 'Admin\Auth\AdminAuthController@getRegister']);
  Route::post('auth/register', 'Admin\Auth\AdminAuthController@postRegister');
```

### });

The routes work, the pages load up fine. The problem Im running into is the loginPath for example if I put in incorrect user/pass it redirect but redirects me to '/auth/login' instead of '/admin/auth/login'.

I found this is being set in AuthenticatesUsers where it checks for loginPath.
I've read on several places that if I add the loginPath to the controller itll overwrite and use that. So in AdminAuthController I have:

---

```
class AdminAuthController extends Controller
{
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

protected $loginPath = '/admin/auth/login';
```

---

but it doesnt use the loginPath I want.
How do I set the loginPath??

Also when I try to create an admin it checks against the Users table, how do I tell it to check against Admin table?

Answer (score -2):

Solved it.

Ended up being my views form action path was pointing incorrectly

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution?

Comment: In the view for the login, the html form tag has an action attribute, you change the path there...  ex: <form action="#####" >